# Raspberry does not recognize bluetooth speaker as output

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu, speakers

This seems to be a googleable question but it doesn't to me.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (RPI) installed Ubuntu 19.10 and a bluetooth speaker "[Amazon Echo Plus First Generation](https://www.ebay.com/p/219488499)" (I know it has many features but I am required to use it as a bluetooth speaker). RPI connect to a monitor via HDMI and pair with the speaker via bluetooth.

- What I want:

I expect that when I play audio on the RPI the speaker would output the audio but it doesn't. However I get the audio correctly on the monitor.

- The problem:

The speaker is now an input device, I even can say "Hey Alexa, what's the weather?" and heard the answer from the monitor. But I cannot select the speaker as output. In the "Input device" field there is only the speaker and in the "Output device" there are 2 options: "Analog output - Built in audio" and "Multichannels output - Built in audio".

- What I tried:

i) A lot of solutions on google is just right-click on the volume icon at the top-right corner and choose the bluetooth speaker as output, but it appears nothing when I right-click on that icon.

ii) Some solutions propose [bluez-alsa](https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/bluetooth_02_en.html#start)

```
aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=30:21:3E:31:C6:2B test16.wav
```

but it seems to be compatible with Raspbian OS only. I have a lot of configuration with other tools and it is just a single step to make everything work, so I quite don't want to switch to Raspbian and reinstall everything.

- The question:

I am appreciate if someone can propose me some solutions on this situation. It is kinda easy from the beginning but it made me stuck for days.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Best Regards,
Will

Comment: Have you try : `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370254/how-can-i-get-the-a2dp-output-option-and-the-input-working-again) ?

Comment: @Ephemeral Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your suggestion, I ran the code and got the result:
"pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused". This is predictable because I do not use Pulse Audio but Alsa.

Comment: `"pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused"` means you have pulse audio installed., have you try the command line without `sudo` ? Maybe also : `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Comment: @Ephemeral I tried to deal with pulse audio but nothing work. I decided to buy a new bluetooth speaker and that solved the problem. Thank you for your suggestion anyway, have a nice day ^^